# The way R handles subseting

Tags: r, subset

I'm having some trouble understanding how R handles subsetting internally and this is causing me some issues while trying to build some functions. Take the following code:

```
f <- function(directory, variable, number_seq) {

  ##Create a empty data frame

  new_frame <- data.frame()

  ## Add every data frame in the directory whose name is in the number_seq to new_frame
  ## the file variable specify the path to the file

  for (i in number_seq){
    file <- paste("~/", directory, "/",sprintf("%03d", i), ".csv", sep = "")
    x <- read.csv(file)
    new_frame <- rbind.data.frame(new_frame, x)
    }

  ## calculate and return the mean
  mean(new_frame[, variable], na.rm = TRUE)*
  }
```

*While calculating the mean I tried to subset first using the `$` sign `new_frame$variable` and the subset function `subset( new_frame, select = variable` but it would only return a None value. It only worked  when I used `new_frame[, variable]`.

Can anyone explain why the other subseting didn't work? It took me a really long time to figure it out and even though I managed to make it work I still don't know why it didn't work in the other ways and I really wanna look inside the black box so I won't have the same issues in the future.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior has to do with the fact that you are subsetting inside a function.

Both `new_frame$variable` and `subset(new_frame, select = variable)` look for a column in the dataframe withe name `variable`.

On the other hand, using `new_frame[, variable]` uses the variablename in `f(directory, variable, number_seq)` to select the column.

Answer (score 1):

The dollar sign (`$`) can only be used with literal column names. That avoids confusion with

```
dd<-data.frame(
    id=1:4,
    var=rnorm(4),
    value=runif(4)
)
var <- "value"
dd$var
```

In this case if `$` took variables or column names, which do you expect? The `dd$var` column or the `dd$value` column (because `var == "value"`). That's why the `dd[, var]` way is different because it only takes character vectors, not expressions referring to column names. You will get `dd$value` with `dd[, var]`

I'm not quite sure why you got `None` with `subset()` I was unable to replicate that problem.